# ¿Como hacer una Consulta Parametrizada en C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2008

En un DropDownList me despliega los titulos que tengo en la base de datos, lo que necesito realizar es un select a cualquiera de los titulos para poder mostrar lo, que al darle click a un titulo tome el id para realizar el select este en mi, por el momento lo tengo con un dato quemado, el codigo  en aspx es:

```
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="ListaArticulo" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListaArticulo_SelectedIndexChanged" style=" margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" Height="30px" BorderColor="#00c0ef"  Width="160px"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Y este es mi código de la capa de Acceso a datos

```
 public Enterate Get_Enterate1(int pid_ent)
    {
        Enterate valor = new Enterate();

        SqlConnection con = null;

        SqlCommand cmd = null;

        SqlDataReader dr = null;

        try
        {              

            con = Conexion.getInstance().ConexionBD();

            con.Open();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.tbenterate WHERE id_ent = 1", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_Id", valor.Id_ent);

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                // Crear objetos de tipo Paciente

                valor.Id_ent = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_ent"].ToString());
                valor.titu_ent = dr["titu_ent"].ToString();
                valor.cod_img_ent = Convert.ToInt16(dr["cod_img_ent"].ToString());
                valor.tip_img_ent = dr["tip_img_ent"].ToString();
                valor.cod_parf_ent = dr["cod_parf_ent"].ToString();
                valor.parf_ent = dr["parf_ent"].ToString();
                valor.fech_art_ent = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fech_art_ent"].ToString());
                valor.img_ent = dr["img_ent"].ToString();

                // añadir a la lista de objetos

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return valor;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que observo es que no defines las propiedades `DataTextField` y `DataValueField` del `DropDownList` para poder usar el `SelectedValue` y tomar la seleccion.

Entonces en tu codigo usarias

```
public Enterate Get_Enterate1(int pid_ent)
{
    try
    {              
        SqlConnection con = Conexion.getInstance().ConexionBD();
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.tbenterate WHERE id_ent = @Id", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", pid_ent);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
           //resto codigo
```

Como observaras cuando defines el parametros debes indicar el nombre y asignarle el valor que pasas por parametro a la funcion

Comment: Muchas gracias, se ve que sabes bastante del tema

Answer (score 1):

Creas tu `SqlCommand` de la misma manera, que lo estas haciendo, solo hay que cambiar el valor de tu `id_ent` por un `?`; de esta manera:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.tbenterate WHERE [id_ent] = ? ", con);
```

Declaras tu parámetro `Id`:

```
var paramId = new SqlParameter(){
   Value = <el valor que el usuario escribió>,
   DbType = SqlDbType.Int,
}
```

Ahora a tu comando hay que agregarle el parámetro:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);
```

Ya que hayas agregado todos los parámetros puedes ejecutar tu comando:

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Espero que te sirva.

Referencias:

- [SqlCommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [SqlCommand.Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: y si hubiera más variables, ¿todas tendrían "?" ?

Comment: asi es, solo hay que agregar los parametros en el mismo orden que los tienes en tu consulta

Comment: ¿El parametro lo declaro en la misma Capa De Acceso A Datos?

Comment: Pues creo que eso dependerá más de tu arquitectura y tus necesidades, pero si puedes declararlo ahí

Comment: Interesante, desconocía que se podía hacer eso; me late que vienes de un background de java o PHP donde se hace de esa manera. Revisa la respuesta de Leandro donde el orden de los "?" carece de importancia y se enfoca en ese nombre temporal que se asigna, generando mayor legibilidad al momento de crear la query.

Comment: no de hecho mi background no abarca mucho ni java ni PHP, en parte es por que he trabajado mas con `C#+SQLite` (aunque tambien permite hacerlo como dice Leandro) y  `Golang+PostgreSQL`, pero la respuesta en esencia es la misma "necesitas agregar params a tu command", tu decides como hacerlo. Saludos.

Comment: Edite la pregunta ya que en la primera no me supe dar a entender correctamente

Comment: no entiendo cual es tu duda ahora

Answer (score 1):

La estructura del codigo para asignar parametros deberia ser como la siguiente

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

string connstring = "connection string";
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connstring)) {

    object query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tbenterate WHERE [id_ent] = @id";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_selectBodegaByFechaSalida", cnn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text));

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

si tienes mas parametros solo agregas otros valores con `@` delante del nombre del parametro y asignas el valor con `Parameters.AddWithValue()`

Comment: Edite la pregunta ya que en la primera no me supe dar a entender correctamente